# Запись куска кода в БД mySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Суть вопроса: в админке движка необходимо сделать поле, `<textarea name="js_field">` в которое администратор будет добавлять произвольный js-код (например, код яндекс метрики, или слайдера, или т.д.). Этот код должен добавляться в таблицу базы mySQL, чтобы потом выводиться в виде php-переменной в темплейте шаблона.

Проблема в том, что когда я пишу в это поле произвольный текст, или html, то добавление происходит нормально. Но когда пишу туда js-код, ничего не добавляется.

Вот пример кода, который я пытаюсь вставить

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({  interval: 40000 });
$('.carousel .item').each(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  if (next.next().length > 0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)).addClass('rightest');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

В чём проблема? Здесь недопустимые символы, или что? Спасибо.

**UPD** Хотя если я вставляю этот код в ячейку напрямую через phpMyAdmin, то всё нормально проходит...

Comment: Приведите код, которым Вы пытаетесь вставить это в базу.

Comment: @Yaant методом post передаю значение в обработчик, который делает такой запрос `UPDATE cms_adm SET title='$title', js_code='$js_code', ... и т.д. ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую.
Если backend часть у Вас на PHP, то заэкранируйте спец символы Вашей строки методом [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php)

Или даже лучше [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: всё верно, спасибо)) век живи, век учись... помогло mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: незачто, обращайся )

Answer (score 0):

Вы также можете воспользоваться данным методом:

```
<?php
$jscode = "here your jscode";
$encode_js = htmlEntities($jscode, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Преобразует все спецсимволы в вашем коде в html сущности, а также используется «ENT_QUOTES», чтобы гарантировать, что XSS невозможно, и ваше приложение безопасно.

Если же вы хотите раскодировать строку (наоборот), используйте html_entity_decode(). Более подробно вы можете почитать: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php#99896

Answer (score 0):

**Не используйте *mysql_real_escape_string***.
Внимание
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него **MySQLi** или **PDO_MySQL**.  Альтернативы для данной функции:

mysqli_real_escape_string() — Экранирует специальные символы в строке для использования в SQL выражении, используя текущий набор символов соединения

PDO::quote() — заключает строку в кавычки (если требуется) и экранирует специальные символы внутри строки подходящим для драйвера способом.